# Buscador de letras de música avanzado

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estoy trabajando en un buscador para una página de Letras de Canciones, el buscador funciona bien, pero no es tan avanzado como lo necesitamos, les cuento por qué.

> Si en la página yo busco: "Ya no vivo por vivir" Funciona.
>
> Si en la página yo busco: "Ya no vivo por vivir Juan Gabriel" NO
> funciona.
>
> Si en la página yo busco: "Ya no vivo por vivir Juan Gabriel" NO
> funciona.
>
> Si en la página yo busco: "Ya no vivo por vivir Juan Gabriel ft
> Natalia" NO funciona.
>
> Si en la página yo busco: "Ya no vivo por vivir Juan Gabriel y
> Natalia" NO funciona.
>
> Si en la página yo busco: "Juan Gabriel" Funciona.

Hay alguna manera de hacer como un match o algún score y combinar las celdas de manera que pueda buscar lo más compatible con la búsqueda? Este es el query que tengo al momento, obtengo los artistas, los artículos y las noticias para retornarlos a la vista, hay alguna manera de juntar los tres queries y hacerlo más inteligente?

```
$blogs = Blog::where('blogs.title', 'like', "%$search%")
            ->where('published', '=', '1')->get();

        $artists = Artist::select('artists.name as name', 'artists.slug as slug', 'artists.slug', 'artists.image')->where('artists.name', 'like', "%$request->search%")
        ->where('artists.status', '=', '1')->get();

        $letters = Letter::select('artists.name as artist', 'artists.slug as artist_slug', 'artists.image', 'letters.slug as letter_slug', 'letters.name', 'letters.approved', 'letters.letter')
        ->join('artists', 'letters.artist_id', '=', 'artists.id')
        ->where('letters.approved', '=', '1')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('letters.name', 'like', "%$search%")
            ->orWhere('artists.name', 'like', "%$search%");
        })
        ->where('letters.reviewed', '!=', null)->get();
```

Comment: Yo metería el nombre del artista en el slug del blog y luego simplemente cogería la cadena de búsqueda y haría un explode por espacios, eliminaría preposiciones etc etc y lo recorrería buscando en el slug del blog solamente.

Answer (score 0):

probaste utilizar **regexp** en vez de **like**, tiene mejor alcance utilizando lenguaje regular en la interacción.

```
 $query->where('letters.name', 'REGEXP', ".*$search.*")
```